# How to add a third level to my CSS drop down menu

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have an existing CSS that only shows a two level menu. I want to add a third level but I'm out of ideas. Could soeone please assist me on what i need to add to the CSS. Below is the current code.

```
#topnav{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    //width:660px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-size:10px;//was 13
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#000000;
}

#topnav ul, #topnav li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#topnav li a:link, #topnav li a:visited, #topnav li a:hover{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:15px 20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#000000;
}

#topnav ul ul li a:link, #topnav ul ul li a:visited{
    border:none;
}

#topnav li.last a{
    margin-right:0;
}

#topnav li a:hover, #topnav ul li.active a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#059BD8;
}

#topnav li li a:link, #topnav li li a:visited{
    //width:150px;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:7px 10px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal; 
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#000000;
}

#topnav li li a:hover{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#059BD8;
}

#topnav li ul{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    height:auto;
    width:170px;
    border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#topnav li ul a{width:140px;}

#topnav li ul ul{margin:-32px 0 0 0;}

#topnav li:hover ul ul{left:-999em;}

#topnav li:hover ul, #topnav li li:hover ul{left:auto;}

#topnav li:hover{position:static;}

#topnav li.last a{margin-right:0;}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="topnav">
    <ul>
        <li <?php if($menu== 0) { echo  "class='active'"; } ?>>
            <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="last">
            <a href="#">Set Up</a>
        <li class="last">
            <a href="#">EMR</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="last" >
                <a href="#">Out-Patient</a>
            </li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Registration</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">File Edition</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="InpatientAdmission.php">In-Patient</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The two sub-menus under out-patient (Registration & File Edition) are not showing.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us a working snippet / fiddle?

Comment: Wrong syntax alert: `//width:150px;` - `//` is not in CSS.

Comment: your html structure is wrong, you've missed to close some elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close a few elements correctly and also the CSS for your solution is:

```css
#topnav li li:hover ul {left: 160px; margin-top: -3em;}
```

Closed and corrected HTML:

```
<div id="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">Set Up</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">EMR</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="last" ><a href="#">Out-Patient</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">File Edition</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="InpatientAdmission.php">In-Patient</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Working Snippet**

```css
#topnav{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  font-size:10px;//was 13
  font-weight:normal;
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#000000;
}
#topnav ul, #topnav li{
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#topnav li a:link, #topnav li a:visited, #topnav li a:hover{
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:15px 20px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#000000;
}



#topnav ul ul li a:link, #topnav ul ul li a:visited{
  border:none;
}

#topnav li.last a{
  margin-right:0;
}

#topnav li a:hover, #topnav ul li.active a{
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#059BD8;
}

#topnav li li a:link, #topnav li li a:visited{
  //width:150px;
  float:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:7px 10px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:normal; 
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#000000;
}

#topnav li li a:hover{
  color:#FFFFFF;
  background-color:#059BD8;
}

#topnav li ul{
  background:#FFFFFF;
  z-index:9999;
  position:absolute;
  left:-999em;
  height:auto;
  width:170px;
  border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;
}



#topnav li ul a{width:140px;}

#topnav li ul ul {margin:-32px 0 0 0;}

#topnav li:hover ul ul{left:-999em;}

#topnav li:hover ul, #topnav li li:hover ul{left:auto;}

#topnav li:hover{position:static;}

#topnav li.last a{margin-right:0;}

#topnav li li:hover ul {left: 160px; margin-top: -3em;}
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">Set Up</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="#">EMR</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="last" ><a href="#">Out-Patient</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">File Edition</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="InpatientAdmission.php">In-Patient</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put your third level menu inside parent li, which makes hierarchical order or level of menu

```
 <li class="last" ><a href="#">Out-Patient</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">File Edition</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 <li>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar in previous code it does not... but i think he edited...anyway your code is good